# Pandas apply if statemen

Tags: pandas, if-statement, apply

I'm trying to change some column value using apply and an if statement.
The condition is very simple and according other answers I've checked it should work but keeps returning an Invalid Syntax error.

`df_personal_info['gender'].apply(lambda x: 'Female' if x == 'Fem' else pass)`

I'm pretty new to this and I am sure it's a silly mistake that I can't see...

Any help will be appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what to `return` from your `lambda` function, which in your case is `x`:

```
df["gender"].apply(lambda x: 'Female' if x == 'Fem' else x)
```

But easier is to use `Series.replace`:

```
df_personal_info["gender"].replace("Fem", "Female")
```

Comment: You're right! It' worked just perfect! Thank you!!

But just to be sure for the next time, what was my mistake?